# Google Apps Script - Query(ImportRange) function returns "Object Does Not Allow Properties to be Updated or Changed"

Tags: google-apps-script

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, and am hoping for some help.  The problem is, I think, in the cellA.setFormula line.  I get an exception - "object does not allow properties to be updated or changed" when I try to execute this function:

```
    function getInfo() {
    //this code used for blue triangle Get Info button.  
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

    var cellA = sheet.getRange("B2");
    cellA.setFormula=("=Query(importRange(\"0Ant11dssJanWdHdhREdjMFgyVDI0OTBIR1BybWRLbkE&usp\";\"Form Responses!A2:AN400\");\"Select Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15,Col16,Col17,Col18,Col19,Col20,Col21,Col22,Col23,Col24,Col25,Col26,Col27,Col28,Col29,Col30,Col31,Col32,Col33,Col34,Col35,Col36,Col37,Col38,Col39,Col40 Where Col4 = '\"&A2&\"' \")");

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because its invalid javascript. Remove the extra '=' after setFormula.

Answer (score 0):

I used this system:

`SpreadsheetApp.openById(PUT ID HERE).getRange('A1').setValue('=IMPORTRANGE(`....

You could change yours to: `cellA.setValue(....`

I hope this helps.